# How to solve android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-viewpager

I use ViewPager LocalActivityManager to load Activitys.When I want to show Dialog in that Activitys .Error shows;It seems that the context used in dialog is not applicable,how to get the right context;

```
vp = (MyViewPager) recommendView.findViewById(R.id.vp);
views = new ArrayList<View>();
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
Intent i2 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Intent i3 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
Intent i4 = new Intent(this, Activity4.class);
Intent i5 = new Intent(this, Activity5.class);
Intent i6 = new Intent(this, Activity6.class);
Intent i7 = new Intent(this, Activity7.class);
views.add(getView("1", i1));
views.add(getView("2", i2));
views.add(getView("3", i3));
views.add(getView("4", i4));
views.add(getView("5", i5));
views.add(getView("6", i6));
views.add(getView("7", i7));
adapter = new MyPageAdapter(views);
vp.setAdapter(adapter);

//getView Code

private View getView(String id, Intent intent) {
    return manager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
}
//show dialog Code

bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Activity7.this);
            dialog.setTitle("title");
            dialog.show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know You wrote it right?
but from the problem ,I think you can try:
define interface in the inside activitys,example;

```
public interface DealDialog{
   public interface showDialog();
}
```

then, implementation this interface in the outside(TabHost).

you can try it.

sorry, My English is so bad, sorry. you can ask me when you don't understand.